# Determining point of discontinuity of a rational function with a root

Tags: calculus, limits, radicals, continuity

For what values of x would the following function be continuous:
$$\frac{\sqrt{3x-6}}{x-5}$$

I know for sure that $x$ cannot equal $5$ because that makes the denominator undefined and then there would be an asymptote there which is an infinite discontinuity. However, I'm not sure if $x$ being less than $2$ makes the function discontinuous as well.

Comment: Please read this [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to type mathematics on this website.

Comment: Your function is defined at 2 not defined less than 2.  At the endpoint of the closed interval you only need to test one of the limits.  i.e.  $\lim_\limits{x\to 2^+} f(x) = f(2)$

Comment: So would one say that the function is continuous everywhere except for 5 or would you have to explicitly state that x cannot be less than 2?

Comment: You shouldn't say "everywhere except at $5$."  It isn't continuous for $x<2,$ because it isn't even defined there.  I would say that it's continuous on $\{x \mid x \ge 2, x \ne 5\},$ or words to that effect.

Comment: This can be tricky and there seems to be lacking an overall consensus: many, and I among them, would say the function is continuous everywhere in its definition domain, which is $\;x\in[2,\infty)\setminus\{5\}\;$ . Others would remark the function isn't continuous at $\;x=5\;$ ...

Comment: @DonAntonio I think the former makes sense only in the case of removable discontinuities and is disingenuous in others, like this case. If $\displaystyle \lim_{x\to r^+} f(x)$ and $\displaystyle \lim_{x\to r^-} f(x)$ both exist and differ it's very clear that $f(x)$ is discontinuous at $r$.

Comment: @orlp I wouldn't call it disingenuous but rather uninformed or overcareful: since the function is completely defined in some neighborhood of $\;5\;$, this may be a way to remark this fact, or the fact that we can (still( evaluate the limit when $\;x\to5\;$, say for vertical asymptotes, etc.